# Connecting HC-05 Transceiver to MSP430G2 using PySerial

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino, pyserial, msp430

So I've been trying to connect [this HC-05 transceiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L083QAC) to my MSP-430G2. Since I'm using a MacBook, I try to send messages using PySerial. I am using:

- OS X 10.9.5
- Python 2.7
- MSP-430G2553
- Energia 0101E0016

This is my Energia code:

```
int gLed = GREEN_LED;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(gLed, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(gLed,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int buf_size = Serial.available();
  if (buf_size > 0) {

    char input = Serial.read();
    if (input == '1'){
      digitalWrite(gLed, HIGH);
    }
    else if (input == '0'){
      digitalWrite(gLed, LOW);
    }
  }    
}
```

After I verify and upload this on the microcontroller, I connect 3.3V to VCC, GND to ground, TXD-RXD from the transceiver to P1.2-P1.1 on the microcontroller (opposite, meaning TXD on transceiver goes into P1.2(RXD) and vice versa), and GND and VCC from the transceiver to the top GND and VCC pins on both sides of the microcontroller. Then I pair my laptop with the HC-05, and I use the following scripts in Python to send messages:

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.HC-05-DevB', baudrate=9600)

s.write('1')
```

What happens is nothing. Absolutely nothing. And it's hard to understand what step I am messing up since it could be any of them. Is it PySerial? Is it how I connect it? Is it my Energia code? Any clue would be greatly helpful. Thank you very much.

UPDATE: This code worked:

```
void loop()
{
  int buf_size = Serial.available();
  if (buf_size > 0) {
      digitalWrite(gLed, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(gLed, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
}
```

The LED started blinking after I finished writing the previous Python script. It might be important to note that it only started blinking after I wrote `s.write('1')` (or any other string as an argument) in Python. Also it doesn't stop after I write `s.close()` and unpair the HC-05 transceiver from my computer.

I think this means a connection is established but some reason the if statements aren't working as they should. Thanks a lot for all you guys' help. I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out what is wrong with the message evaluation too.

UPDATE 2: This code also worked:

```
void loop()
{
  int buf_size = Serial.available();
  if (buf_size > 0) {
      char input = Serial.read();
      if (input){
        digitalWrite(gLed, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(gLed, LOW);
        delay(1000);
    }
  }    
}
```

Any time I sent an input, the light turned on and then off. It remained off until I sent another input. I think this means the inputs are received by the transceiver and relayed to the microprocessor. The issue might be that the inputs I am sending are not understood by the microprocessor however.

The issue is that I am sending single byte char messages that I had previously determined in my Energia code. I am using Python 2.7 and I tried many different ways to send messages from PySerial including: `s.write('1')`, `s.write(1)`, `s.write(b'1')`, `s.write('1'.encode())`, `s.write(bytearray('1'))`. At this point, I really don't know how to send it in a way that will help me solve this issue, but I believe I was able to narrow it down to PySerial at this point.

UPDATE 3: The situation is getting weirder. After making the MCU blink according to its input I noticed the following situation.

When I used `s.write('1')` the received binary by the bluetooth transceiver was '11110100.' After this I tried using `s.write('2')` and `s.write('3')` and I realized that they were received as the same binary by my MCU: '11110100.' The next thing I did was trying `s.write('4')` and I realized it gave the same result as `s.write('1')`. I wrote the following script to try it (also includes the script to print out input by LED blinking).

```
void loop()
{
  int buf_size = Serial.available();
  if (buf_size > 0) {
    char input = Serial.read();
    if (byte(input) == B11110100){
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
          digitalWrite(rLed, HIGH);
          delay(100);
          digitalWrite(rLed, LOW);
          delay(100);
      }
    }
    else if (input){
        digitalWrite(gLed, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(rLed, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(gLed, LOW);
        digitalWrite(rLed, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        for (int i=0; i < 8; i++){
          int val = bitRead(input,i);  // get the voltage from the microphone
          if (val == 0){
              digitalWrite(rLed, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(rLed, LOW);
          }
          else if (val == 1){
              digitalWrite(gLed, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(gLed, LOW);
          }
          delay(1000);
       }
    }
  }  
}
```

Both `s.write('1')` and `s.write('4')` give the same output. Anyone have any idea what this could be about? Thanks a lot for your help and time.

SOLUTION: I realized Energia wasn't set up to work with my MSP model but a closely related one. Fixing that fixed all issues. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Does a simple LED blink program work? Does a program that blindly sends serial data work?

Comment: Would a simple LED blink program that you suggest just involve having the LED blank without looking at an input? What does blindly sending serial data entail? How can I check if it works?

Comment: I checked the first idea and posted an update. Thank you for helping me get a little closer to figuring this out!

Comment: Output all eight bits of the received byte: short blink for a 0 bit, long for 1.

Comment: So I tried it for s.write('1'). I got this byte '11110100.' Actually it gets messier, I got the same for '4.' I got '11110101' for '2' and '3.' These calls all returned 1, which I believe refers to the number of bytes being transferred. I have no idea what is happening but it's just weird at this point.

Comment: I was able to verify that this strangeness is indeed the case. I will add an update.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an HC-06 to connect the serial port of an Arduino with a MacBook before and the tricky part was finding the right port.
Once its paired, list the available ports with `ls /dev/{tty,cu}.*` and try a different one. For me it showed two different ports for a single device.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just did what you suggested, and checked all the ports that came up, none worked unfortunately. I think the one I use is the one that refers to the bluetooth transceiver however, since s.close() unpaired the HC-05, and s.open() repaired it.

To add, I had a cu, and a tty for the same device but neither worked.